# Modify opacity based off of AnalyserNode data

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I am attempting to animate the opacity of some text based off the volume of an audio file.

I found [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mandymichael/pen/OYpqdP) which does nearly the same thing, but I am fairly new to JS and can't quite parse what Mandy is doing in regards to SCSS and Variable Font axis.

I simply want to modulate opacity between 0 and 1.

**HTML**

```
<p class="animating-text">Lorem ipsum bacon!</p>
```

**Javascript** (I did my best to take a shot at what I am trying to do based off the linked demo)

```
// Audio code from Ruth's Demo!! - https://codepen.io/Rumyra/pen/jomXeG
console.clear;
// create audio context and make sure it gets activated
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let data = new Uint8Array(2);

// create analyser 
const analyserNode = new AnalyserNode(audioCtx, {
    fftSize: 64,
    maxDecibels: -25,
    minDecibels: -60,
    smoothingTimeConstant: 0.5,
});

function getAnalyserData() {
    requestAnimationFrame(getAnalyserData);
    analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(data);

    const minOpacity = 0;
    const maxOpacity = 1;

    const minEventValue = 0;
    const maxEventValue = 255;

    // Get the current event value
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName("animating-text");
    element.style.opacity = "0";

    if (data[0] === 255) {
        element.style.opacity = "1";
        return
    } else {
        /// not quite clear what to do here
  }
}

// set draw after stream has started
function getStreamData() {
    // pipe in analysing to getUserMedia
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
        .then(stream => audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream))
        .then(source => {
            source.connect(analyserNode);
        });
}

// resume
window.addEventListener("click", event => {
    audioCtx.resume();
    getStreamData().then(getAnalyserData);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample in this link https://codepen.io/LakshithaMadushan/pen/VwvxVNM

1) Comment `font-variation-settings: "yest" var(--yest);`  **and add**  `opacity: var(--yest);` **below that in the style.css**

2) In the script.js file, last line of **fluidAxisVariation** function we need update as `element.style.setProperty(axisCustomPropertyName, newAxisValue/1000);`. 
(We need to modulate opacity between 0 and 1 so that's why newAxisValue divided by 1000)